# how to install IOCTL man pages for STREAMS in ubuntu server?

Tags: c, linux, ioctl, manpage

in my system

```
Linux ubuntu 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu
```

man page for `putmsg` contains reference to STREAMS man page. Stevens refers the same entity as STREAMIO (p. 858), and this is what I've found online:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man7/stropts.h.7posix.html#contenttoc0

However, I can't find neither the local man page, nor how to add it locally. Please, advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"So from a technical point of view streams is dead" -- Alan Cox in https://lkml.org/lkml/1998/6/28/138 and yes that 1998 in the URL is the year, so it's at least 15 years past dead now.

STREAMS is not implemented in GNU/Linux. You can get a set of man pages that describe the interface as specified by POSIX by installing the `manpages-posix` and `manpages-posix-dev` packages, but you're wasting your time reading about STREAMS if your interest is anything but historical.

Of the two add-on implementations of STREAMS for Linux mentioned in [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STREAMS), one is a dead link and the other one goes to a site (openss7.org) which is focused entirely on telephone switching, and hasn't been updated since 2008.